# How can I catch all the url requests of a specific directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, subdirectory

Suppose that we have all these URLs:

```
http://www.xxx.co/directory/something
http://www.xxx.co/directory/somethingelse
https://www.xxx.co/directory/somethinginHTTPS
http://www.xxx.co/directory/something/withotherthing
http://www.xxx.co/directory/something/page.html
```

I need a .htaccess inside the directory "directory" to catch all these URLs that get into that directory and process them at

```
http://www.xxx.co/directory/index.php
```

without changing the original URL in the browser.

How can I do that?

ANSWER ===================================================

I have found a solution but I have forgotten to paste it here. So here it is. Inside the "directory" folder, place a .htaccess file with the following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in the index.php inside the same folder, you can inspect the requested address and work with it.

```
<?php
$url =parse_url((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");

echo "<pre>";
echo $url["path"];
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear what you are asking.  Do you mean to redirect/rewrite `/directory/anyPath` to `/directory/index.php` ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Please help me to re-formulate if you think my question is not clear.